# Combinations Among Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Problem:
Which of the following is true?

$\begin{pmatrix}A\cup B\\2\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}A\\2\end{pmatrix}\cup
\begin{pmatrix}B\\2\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}A\cap B\\2\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}A\\2\end{pmatrix}\cap
\begin{pmatrix}B\\2\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}A\cup B\\2\end{pmatrix}
\supseteq
\begin{pmatrix}A\\2\end{pmatrix}\cup
\begin{pmatrix}B\\2\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}A\cap B\\2\end{pmatrix}
\subseteq
\begin{pmatrix}A\\2\end{pmatrix}\cap
\begin{pmatrix}B\\2\end{pmatrix}$

It seems to me that only the first one is strictly false, while the other three seem to be true. My best answer is that the last two are incorrect because they will never be subsets of the other, only equal. I couldn't think of counterexamples.

Comment: The 2-subsets of $A\cup B$ include the 2-subsets of $A$, and also the 2-subsets of $B$, no? The $\subseteq$ notation allows for equality.

Comment: You should define what your notation means. (I'd say that the notation $\binom A2$, where $A$ is a set, is not very common.)

Comment: @Martin, in some circles, it's standard for the 2-element subsets of $A$.

Comment: @Gerry: Given any context to speak of, it’s pretty self-explanatory, and I have seen it occasionally, but mostly here, so I’m curious: do you happen to know in what circles it’s standard?

Comment: @Brian, you've called my bluff ... I've just seen it enough (mostly, as you note, here) that I assumed it had to be standard somewhere.

Comment: @Gerry: Oh, well! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The last three are true for all sets $A$ and $B$.

Take the third, for instance: if $S\in\binom{A}2\cup\binom{B}2$, then certainly $S\in\binom{A\cup B}2$, so $\binom{A\cup B}2\supseteq\binom{A}2\cup\binom{B}2$. Equality is possible: if $A\subseteq B$, for instance, then $\binom{A}2\subseteq\binom{B}2$, and $A\cup B=B$, so $$\binom{A}2\cup\binom{B}2=\binom{B}2=\binom{A\cup B}2\;.$$ On the other hand, if there are elements $a\in A\setminus B$ and $b\in B\setminus A$, then $$\{a,b\}=\binom{A\cup B}2\setminus\left(\binom{A}2\cup\binom{B}2\right)\;,$$ and $$\binom{A\cup B}2\supsetneqq\binom{A}2\cup\binom{B}2\;.$$

The fact that the second is true does not mean that the fourth isn’t true; In fact, the second **implies** the fourth: if $X$ and $Y$ are sets, and we know that $X=Y$, then we certainly know that $X\subseteq Y$. This is analogous to the situation with real numbers: if $x=y$, then it’s certainly true that $x\le y$.

The only one that is not always true is the first, and even it is true for some choices of $A$ and $B$. In fact it’s true precisely when $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$; in all other cases we can find elements $a\in A\setminus B$ and $b\in B\setminus A$, and we’ve saw above that in that case the first assertion is false.